# C3 js dynamic bindto

Tags: javascript, angularjs, c3.js

I am using [C3.js](http://c3js.org/) to render a gauge chart in my angular application. There are multiple charts on the webpage and their order and id is determined at runtime.

I have a service called `WidgetService` that renders different types of charts. I call the `setup` method of the graph object on `ng-init` of the `div`.

Here's the `setup` method:

```
this.setup = function() {
  var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#' + this.id,
    data: {
      columns: [
        ['data', this.data]
      ],
      type: 'gauge',
    },
    size: { height: 180 }
  });

  console.log("in setup");
};
```

The `id` for each chart is evaluated at runtime and because of that `bindto` is failing to bind the chart to the html element. If I hard code the `id` it works fine. Is there any way I can achieve this dynamic binding?

Here's the fiddle of the complete example that is similar to the structure of my application: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prerak6962/htm4yssL/27/).

I have included only one chart in the fiddle (gauge) but actually there are different types of charts. Each chart has its own directive (e.g `gauge-chart` for gauge chart) and its implementation in the `WidgetService`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
bindto: document.getElementById(this.id)
```

works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

One of these would work:

```
bindto: '#myContainer'
// or element
bindto: document.getElementById('myContainer')
// or D3 selection object
bindto: d3.select('#myContainer')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="chart0"></div>
<div class="chart1"></div>
<div class="chart2"></div>
<div class="chart3"></div>
<div class="chart4"></div>
<div class="chart5"></div>
<div class="chart6"></div>
<div class="chart7"></div>
<div class="chart8"></div>
<div class="chart9"></div>
<div id="chart"></div>
$('#chart').attr("id", "chart" + i);
$(".chart" + i).attr("id", "chart");
```

if used inside loop.
The same could be used outside of loop also, just change i according to your requirements
Above could be used to generate 10 charts. It's tested